# How to do loess normalization in R using affy package?

Tags: r, loess

I  want to do loess normalization with a batch of Agilent txt files for mRNA information, using the 'affy' package. I have gone through the manual but am not being able to understand the prerequisites [I am new to R and am proceeding through a trial-and-error based learning]. Would someone please explain how to do it?